# Traversing a management tree in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display all the employees under a given manager.  All of the employees have the UserID of their immediate supervisor in their user record but not the supervisor above them.  Basically what I am trying to do is if I put a director's ID which is 2 levels above me I want to see my ID along with everybody else under that director.  Is this possible SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a hierarchical or recursive query.

To get the hierarchy under a given manager, instead of rooting the tree at the top

```
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, ManagerID, 1
    FROM Employees
    WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
```

you would root the tree at the desired manager

```
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, ManagerID, 1
    FROM Employees
    WHERE ManagerID = @QueryManagerID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather generic Recursive CTE for a rather generic quesion

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (UserID varchar(25),ManagerID varchar(25),Name varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values 
 ('usr1' ,NULL   ,'A')
,('usr2' ,'usr1' ,'B')
,('usr3' ,'usr2' ,'F')
,('usr4' ,'usr3' ,'C')
,('usr5' ,'usr3' ,'D')
,('usr8' ,'usr1' ,'M')
,('usr9' ,'usr8' ,'N')
,('usr10','usr8' ,'O')
,('usr11','usr10','P')

Declare @Top  varchar(25) = null      --<<  Sets top of Hier Try usr3 
Declare @Nest varchar(25) = '|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(10000+Row_Number() over (Order by Name) as varchar(500))
            ,UserID
            ,ManagerID 
            ,Lvl=1
            ,Name
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(ManagerID ,-1) else UserID end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',10000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.Name)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.UserID
            ,r.ManagerID 
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.Name 
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.ManagerID  = p.UserID)
     ,cteR1 as (Select *,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteP)
     ,cteR2 as (Select A.UserID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.UserID )
Select A.R1  
      ,B.R2
      ,A.UserID
      ,A.ManagerID 
      ,A.Lvl
      ,Name = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.Name
 From  cteR1 A
 Join  cteR2 B on A.UserID=B.UserID
 Order By Seq
```

**Returns Full Hierarchy (when @Top = null)**

[image]

**Returns Hierarchy Portion (when @Top = 'someUserID')**

[image]

**A few Comments**

You may notice the Range Keys (R1/R2).  These are optional and can be removed. However, they aid in navigation, selection, and/or aggregation without the need for recursive queries.

Most management hierarchies are slow-moving, so I would recommend storing the results into an actual table and rebuilding as needed.   This would be more performant, especially if you have a large organization.  This leads me to one final point.  LARGE recursive CTEs tend not to perform well.  There are other techniques which can be deployed

Comment: I would add a materialized path to your generic hierarchy traversal, it may also aid in readability, e.g. http://rextester.com/KIZQRE86151

Comment: @SqlZim Always a good option, but I've found the range keys offer better performance especially when navigating large hierarchies (200K+) and aggregating large data (4.6B rows).   Over time, I've created a collection of helper functions to manage and navigate. Years ago, I thought I was the smartest guy on two legs when I "Invented" the range keys.  I was discussing them with an IBM Consultant, and he quietly leaned in and said "We call them the Speed Keys"

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you switch to using the materialized path for navigating, traversal, or aggregating anything.  I just meant including it as a readability aid.